# Which foods and ingredients are the main sources of fibre in traditional Lao cuisine?

Tags: asian-cuisine

I'm taking an interest lately in Lao cuisine (I'm in the country). But I haven't noticed where they get their fibre from.

Which traditional dishes or ingredients should I investigate?

Comment: What do you mean by "fibre" in this context?

Comment: Dietary fibre, that keeps you regular (-: I tried to avoid anything that made it sound like a health and nutrition question and keep it to a factual question.

Comment: As in non-digestible polysaccharides?

Comment: As in "roughage". Non digestible. Not sure about the polysaccharides, it's not my field.

Comment: Reading the lao cuisine wiki article, they seem to be a fairly typical Asian cuisine with a lot of vegetables.  I suspect that is your answer: the cellulose in the cell walls of most vegetables is not digestible.

Comment: Yes they actually serve a plate of raw greens with most traditional meals too. Would raw green/leaf vegetables mean more fibre too? I think this is a peculiarity of Lao cuisine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10629/discussion-between-saj14saj-and-hippietrail)

Answer (score 1):

Papaya salad(tam mak hoong) has firbre.